# How to count rows of database and show it at laravel 5.4 view?

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm new at laravel. I'm working on new web application using laravel 5.4. I want to count the number of data in a database and show the result in view. So, I have used this code in controller:

```
public function bending_img(){
    $counts = requestImg::where('is_done', '=', '0')->count();
    return view('/dashboard')->with(['counts'=> $counts]);
}

public function uploaded_img(){
    $count = requestImg::where('is_done', '=', '1')->count();
    return view('/dashboard')->with(['count'=> $count]);
}
```

and in view:

```
@if(count($counts)== 0)
         no call record to be viewed
@else
         <div class="huge">{{$counts}}</div>
@endif

@if(count($count)==0)
         no call record to be viewed
@else
         <div class="huge">{{$count}}</div>
@endif
```

but there is an error: `undefined variable`.

Please resolve this error.

Comment: you shouldn't count it twice (in your controller and then again in the view). The first one (in the controller) should be enough.

Comment: It's two different cases that's why I count it twice , anyway I don't think this is the problem. My issue is how to show the result in view without that error!

Comment: Are you executing both functions? They each return a the same view.

Comment: I have one column called (is_done), some of its data is 0 and the other is 1, I want to show the "0" data at a div and the "1" data at another div but both in the same view. that is why I have made two functions.

Comment: @Y.EzzEldin That is not going to work, I gave an answer, but I am not sure if that is what you mean.

Comment: it gives the same error: "Undefined variable: bendingImgCount" . Is there a problem at calling the function?

Comment: what is the path of your view?

Comment: That is the full path: http://localhost/img_store/public/dashboard. so I wrote it in controller: ('/dashboard')

Answer (score 0):

```
public function bendingImgCount() {
    return requestImg::where('is_done', '0')->count();
}

public function uploadedImgCount() {
    return = requestImg::where('is_done', '1')->count();
}

public function showDashboard() {
    $bendingImgCount = $this->bendingImgCount();
    $uploadedImgCount = $this->uploadedImgCount();

    return view('/dashboard')->with(compact(['bendingImgCount', 'uploadedImgCount']));
}
```

Call the showDashboard function and change in the view the counts to bendingImgCount and count to uploadedImgCount.

Comment: It gives the same error: "Undefined variable: bendingImgCount" . Should I have to define the variable in view before calling it there? If yes, I don't know how!

Answer (score 0):

First you check wherether you get correct data at controller
You just simply

```
public function bending_img(){
    $counts = requestImg::where('is_done', '=', '0')->count();
    dd($counts);
    return view('/dashboard')->with(['counts'=> $counts]);
}

public function uploaded_img(){
    $count = requestImg::where('is_done', '=', '1')->count();
    dd($count);
    return view('/dashboard')->with(['count'=> $count]);
}
```

And check you get correct answer or not .

Comment: there is  at no result at all !

Answer (score 0):

I am getting Correct count in browser

1.Controller Page:

[image]

2.web.php Page:

[image]

3.Web Browser:
[image]

If you are even not getting correct value then just show your whole code of page.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS:

In Controller:

```
public function bending_img(){
    $counts = requestImg::where('is_done', '=', '0')->count();
    return view('/dashboard')->with('this_is_it', $counts);
}

public function uploaded_img(){
    $count = requestImg::where('is_done', '=', '1')->count();
    return view('/dashboard')->with('count_1',$count);
}
```

In View:

```
@if(count($this_is_it)== 0)
         no call record to be viewed
@else
         <div class="huge">{{$this_is_it}}</div>
@endif

@if(count($count_1)==0)
         no call record to be viewed
@else
         <div class="huge">{{$count_1}}</div>
@endif
```